# how to exit Gallium debugger?

Tags: debugging, julia, gallium

what's the command to exit the Gallium debugger for Julia? I tried all things like `q`, `Q`, `exit()`,  `exit`, `Ctrl-c`.

```
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?help" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.5.0 (2016-09-19 18:14 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0

julia> using Gallium

julia> include(Pkg.dir("Gallium/examples/testprograms/misc.jl"))
optional (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> Gallium.breakpoint(sinthesin,Tuple{Int64})

Locations (+: active, -: inactive, *: source):
 + sinthesin(x::Int64) at /Users/florian.oswald/.julia/v0.5/Gallium/examples/testprograms/misc.jl:2


julia> inaloop(2)
In /Users/florian.oswald/.julia/v0.5/Gallium/examples/testprograms/misc.jl:2
1 @noinline function sinthesin(x)
2     sin(sin(x))
3 end
4 

About to run: Main.sin
1|debug > q
In /Users/florian.oswald/.julia/v0.5/Gallium/examples/testprograms/misc.jl:2
1 @noinline function sinthesin(x)
2     sin(sin(x))
3 end
4 

About to run: Main.sin
1|debug >
```

**UPDATE**

there is a related [issue](https://github.com/Keno/Gallium.jl/issues/177) on github. The main takeaway from this is to use `@enter func(x,y)` and step into a function directly. i find this works pretty well.

Comment: In fact, the functionality of `q` is `continue`. In your example, a breakpoint was assigned on  `sinthesin` and `inaloop(2)` called it twice, so you need to `q`(`continue`) twice to exit the debugger.

Comment: ok cool thanks. I'll just add here that `Ctrl-d` works right away.

Comment: i still have problems with this. i cannot exit with ctrl-d when i set a @conditional breakpoint.

Comment: maybe we should file an issue? But it seems keno is very busy recently. @DNF

Answer (score 2):

When working with REPL, you can use `finish` to exit the current function. To exit debugger, you may need to execute this command several times.

In Atom, the corresponding command is the `Debug: Finish Function` button.

You can find more commands [here](https://github.com/Keno/ASTInterpreter.jl#astinterpreter).

### UPDATE:

A breakpoint pauses the program whenever a certain point in the program is reached. In your example, `inaloop(2)` will call `sinthesin` twice, so a single `q` or `Ctrl+d` is not enough to exit the debugger. I think this is the expected behavior, take a look at the following example:

```
julia> bp = Gallium.breakpoint(sinthesin,Tuple{Int64})
Locations (+: active, -: inactive, *: source):
 + sinthesin(x::Int64) at /Users/gnimuc/.julia/v0.5/Gallium/examples/testprograms/misc.jl:2


julia> inaloop(2)
In /Users/gnimuc/.julia/v0.5/Gallium/examples/testprograms/misc.jl:2
1 @noinline function sinthesin(x)
2     sin(sin(x))
3 end
4 

About to run: Main.sin
1|debug > q
In /Users/gnimuc/.julia/v0.5/Gallium/examples/testprograms/misc.jl:2
1 @noinline function sinthesin(x)
2     sin(sin(x))
3 end
4 

About to run: Main.sin
1|debug > q

julia> 

julia> Gallium.disable(bp)
true

julia> @enter inaloop(2)
In /Users/gnimuc/.julia/v0.5/Gallium/examples/testprograms/misc.jl:6
5 @noinline function inaloop(y)
6     for i = 1:y
7   sinthesin(i)
8     end

About to run: (colon)(1,2)
1|debug > q
```

Comment: I am stuck at a breakpoint in a function which is being called in a loop that will run tens or hundreds of thousands of times. Is there then no recourse except killing Julia completely?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Gnimuc's answer you should also be able to exit the debugger with the `q` command.

From [here](https://github.com/Keno/ASTInterpreter.jl/blob/master/src/ASTInterpreter.jl#L1667):

```
const all_commands = ("q", "s", "si", "finish", "bt", "loc", "ind", "shadow",
        "up", "down", "ns", "nc", "n", "se")
```

Comment: I've had success with `q` and `Ctrl+d` in the REPL. Where are you using Gallium?  The terminal or Atom?

Comment: `Ctrl+d` works! yes mac os terminal. `q` does not work.

Comment: @Florian Oswald `q` works. I've just tested it on my machine.

Comment: I told you it doesn't work on my computer. see edited question.